# Associative find causes integrity constraint violation when same field names

Tags: cakephp

I am facing CakePHP2 problem that I can't get through. I have model associated to another by "belongsTo "definition and it for fine BUT when I try to retrieve associated data query dies with following error. It seems to have problem with table field names. Both, Accounting and CLetter tables has "date" columns. How should I build query to fetch all data from both tables with date columns included?

Even better would be that this configuration could be done in Accounting model. so i could just do where ever I want like this (currently produces followinf error message)

```
$Accounting->find('all', 'recursive' => 2);
```

Error message

```
Running AccountingTestCase

PDOEXCEPTION
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'date' in field list is ambiguous
Test case: AccountingTestCase(testCancelAccounting)
Stack trace:
C:\xampp\htdocs\Galactica\lib\Cake\Model\Datasource\DboSource.php : 460
C:\xampp\htdocs\Galactica\lib\Cake\Model\Datasource\DboSource.php : 426
C:\xampp\htdocs\Galactica\lib\Cake\Model\Datasource\DboSource.php : 666
C:\xampp\htdocs\Galactica\lib\Cake\Model\Datasource\DboSource.php : 1077
C:\xampp\htdocs\Galactica\lib\Cake\Model\Model.php : 2750
C:\xampp\htdocs\Galactica\lib\Cake\Model\Model.php : 2722
C:\xampp\htdocs\Galactica\app\Plugin\AccountingPlugin\Test\Case\Model\AccountingTest.php : 34
AccountingTestCase::testCancelAccounting
C:\xampp\php\pear\PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase.php : 976
C:\xampp\php\pear\PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase.php : 831
C:\xampp\php\pear\PHPUnit\Framework\TestResult.php : 648
C:\xampp\php\pear\PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase.php : 776
C:\xampp\htdocs\Galactica\lib\Cake\TestSuite\CakeTestCase.php : 84
C:\xampp\php\pear\PHPUnit\Framework\TestSuite.php : 775
C:\xampp\php\pear\PHPUnit\Framework\TestSuite.php : 745
C:\xampp\php\pear\PHPUnit\TextUI\TestRunner.php : 349
C:\xampp\htdocs\Galactica\lib\Cake\TestSuite\CakeTestRunner.php : 63
C:\xampp\htdocs\Galactica\lib\Cake\TestSuite\CakeTestSuiteCommand.php : 97
C:\xampp\htdocs\Galactica\lib\Cake\TestSuite\CakeTestSuiteDispatcher.php : 247
C:\xampp\htdocs\Galactica\lib\Cake\TestSuite\CakeTestSuiteDispatcher.php : 100
C:\xampp\htdocs\Galactica\lib\Cake\TestSuite\CakeTestSuiteDispatcher.php : 117
C:\xampp\htdocs\Galactica\app\webroot\test.php : 92
1/1 test methods complete: 0 passes, 0 fails, 1 assertions and 1 exceptions.
```

Query code itself (produces error message):

```
$accountingsList = $Accounting->find('all', [
    'contain' => ['CLetter'],
    'conditions' => ['Accounting.date' => date('Y-m-d')]
]);
```

Accounting model association:

```
public $belongsTo = [
    'CLetter' => ['foreignKey' => 'f_letter'],
    'ProfitLetter' => ['className' => 'CLetter', 'foreignKey' => 'f_profit_accounting_letter'],
    'ContactBusiness' => ['foreignKey' => 'f_contact_business']
];
```

CLetter model association:

```
public $hasMany = array(
    'Accounting' => array('foreignKey' => 'f_letter'),
    'PayContract' => array('foreignKey' => 'f_letter'),
    'PayContractLastInstallment' => array(
        'className' => 'PayContract',
        'foreignKey' => 'f_last_installment_letter'));
```

### EDIT

This works, but I would really like to move this field part to the model associations that I could retrieve data with find->('all') and no extra parameters. Is this possible?

```
$accountingsList = $Accounting->find('all', [
    'fields' => ['CLetter.*', 'Accounting.*'],
    'conditions' => ['Accounting' => ['Accounting.date' => date('Y-m-d')]],
]);
```

### EDIT2

Ok. I was able to solve this by adding following code to AppModel, but is this really the only way to get through this? I think this should be default behavior in CakePHP when selecting fields from table.

```
public function beforeFind($queryData)
{
    if (empty($queryData['fields'])) {
        $schema = $this->schema();
        foreach (array_keys($schema) as $field) {
            $queryData['fields'][] = $this->alias . '.' . $field;
        }

        return $queryData;
    }

    return parent::beforeFind($queryData);
}
```

### EDIT3

Problem still occurs. Solution in EDIT2 causes Containable behavior to stop working completely. Any advise here?

Answer (score 0):

when you specify a relationship between models you can also set the fields you want to retrieve by default

from the [manual](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#belongsto):

> **fields**: A list of fields to be retrieved when the associated model
>   data is fetched. Returns all fields by default.

Comment: Yes but this drives me to either specifying all the table names manually. This is not very flexible option if database schema changes (and it will, in this case). Although, I noticed that specifying all field names manually, fixes my problem but it is not solution here. It seems that manually table prefix is added to query and if field list is not given it just does "CLetter.*, Accounting.*" which causes conflict with date field.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Problem was strange but obvious: There was following definition in CLetter model what is indeed ambigious:

```
public $virtualFields = array('Y' => "YEAR(date)", 'M' => "MONTH(date)", 'n' => "count(*)");
```

Fixed this by changing it to:

```
public $virtualFields = array('Y' => "YEAR(CLetter.date)", 'M' => "MONTH(CLetter.date)", 'n' => "count(*)");
```